# how to increase the file extension numerically by one

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename

under the following current folder, we have the example of files

```
lok.log.1
df.log.6
weq.log.90
vr.log.11
vs.aw.frsd.log.3
```

we want to increase the files extension by 1

so the expected output will be as the following

```
lok.log.2
df.log.7
weq.log.91
vr.log.12
vs.aw.frsd.log.4
```

please advice how to rename the files with find and regex

- The concept should be all the files that have ".log" will be renamed by +1

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"with find and regex"* - if you have one of the perl-based `rename` commands, you could do something like `rename -- 's/(\d+)$/$1+1/e' *.log.*` I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n -f '(*.log.)(<->)(#qnOn)' '$1$(($2+1))'
```

(remove the `-n` if satisfied with the result)

- `<->` matches any decimal number
- `(#qnOn)`: glob qualifier here to sort the list of files numerically (`n`) in reverse order by name (`On`) so `file.log.2` is renamed to `file.log.3` before `file.log.1` is renamed to `file.log.2`. Add `.` if you want to rename only *regular* files (but then you would probably want to add a `-o-nT` option assuming GNU `mv`) and `D` if you also want to rename hidden files.
- `-f` disables the safeguard that would cancel that command when a file would be renamed to an existing file which would get in the way in our `file.log.1`, `file.log.2` example above. It would still guard against both `foo.log.1` and `foo.log.01` being renamed to `foo.log.2`.

Recursively:

```
zmv -n -f '(**/)(*.log.)(<->)(#qnOn)' '$1$2$(($3+1))'
```

From `bash` or `sh` or `ksh`:

```
zsh << 'EOF'
autoload zmv
zmv -n -f '(*.log.)(<->)(#qnOn)' '$1$(($2+1))'
EOF
```

With `bash` and without using `zsh`, and if you have GNU `ls` and GNU `mv`, and the list of files is not too big, you can do something approaching with:

```
shopt -s failglob
shopt -s extglob
export LC_ALL=C
eval "files=($(
  ls --quoting-style=shell-always -rvd -- *.log.+([[:digit:]])))"
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
   echo mv -nT -- "$f" "${f%.*}.$((10#${f##*.} + 1))"
done
```

(remove `echo` when satisfied).

Recursively, with GNU `bash`, GNU `find`, GNU `mv` and GNU `sort`, for regular files only:

```
export LC_ALL=C
while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 file; do
  echo mv -nT "$file" "${file%.*}.$((10#${file##*.} + 1))"
done 3< <(
  find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -regex '.*\.log\.[0-9]+' -type f -print0 |
    sort -rzV)
```

`mv -n` is a GNU extension to avoid clobbering existing files, and `-T` to remove the ambiguity between *move to* and *move into* which `mv` otherwise suffers from. Note however that when a file is not renamed because of `-n`, you don't get any error about that.

Comment: should be under shell script as bash / ksh / sh

Comment: @yael, see edit.

Comment: autoload zmv
bash: autoload: command not found...

Comment: any way as I asked we prefer to do the rename with find and regex

Comment: @yael, from bash, you need to use the `zsh << ...` syntax. I've added a variant for GNU systems without `zsh` installed.

Comment: Note that in all solutions this will happen: `mv -- file.log.00024  file.log.25`. Don't think that that is what is expected. Maybe something like `zmv -n -f '(*.log.)(<->)(#qnOn)' '$1$(printf %0\*d ${#2} $(($2+1)))'` and similar for bash.

Comment: @Isaac, about 0-padding, I thought of that, hinted to it as a limitation but left it off as it was not asked for. Also, you'd still have the problem that when you have 01 -> 99, you'd probably want to change to 002 -> 100 but probably not in the 1 -> 9 case. IMO, that's better left for another question.

Comment: Why LC_ALL? For sort? or Has it a wider effect?

Comment: LC_ALL=C because filenames are arbitrary sequences of bytes which may not form valid characters. At least GNU `find`'s `-name '.?*'` would fail to match hidden files whose name contains sequence of byte that don't form valid characters in the current locale. I'd  rather not take the risk of using `eval` on the output of `ls --quot...` in locales other than C.

Comment: @Issac, `mv -nT` should prevent the overwriting of any file (or moving files into directory instead of renaming). It's annoying that it doesn't report an error when it would clobber a file though. Even `mv -nvT` is silent in that case.  `mv -i < /dev/null` doesn't report a non-zero exit status either and leaves a non-terminated prompt line on stderr.

Comment: Ahhh, eval, I get it. So, maybe the last one might not need (not that I am asking you to change it) such wide use for "LC_ALL..." but only for sort, hmmm, I'll test it later, thanks, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

`rename` is `perl`-based and allows using arithmetics  (some distros use the name `prename` for this `perl` renaming tool) :

```
rename 's/(log.)([0-9]+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' <files>
```

To combine with find, use:

```
find <search options> -exec rename 's/(log.)([0-9]+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' {} +
```

---

Edit following Stéphane's comment:

The unsorted output of `find` might indeed trouble you and it better be sorted beforehand. We can use reverse (!) sort and its version numbering option for the given name patterns:

```
find <search parpameters> -print0 |\
   sort -rzV |\
   xargs -r0 rename 's/(log.)([0-9]+)$/$1.($2+1)/e'
```

Comment: Beware `find` processes files in an unsorted way. If it finds `file.log.1` before `file.log.2`, that won't work properly.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas good point. `sort` will help out here.

Comment: You want **reverse** version sort here. You don't need to call one `rename` per file. `xargs -r0 rename ...` should be enough and more efficient. See my answer for other caveats.

Comment: `rename` seems to be incredibly slow in the first place.

Comment: slow to start (as it's `perl`) but not slow to run. Beware there are different variants of perl's `rename`, some which will take care of not overwriting files by default (but fail in some corner cases), some that won't. In any case, calling `rename` on many files should be significantly faster that calling one `mv` for each of those files (unless you use a shell with `mv` builtin like `zsh`/`ksh93` where `mv` _can_ be made builtin).

Comment: `-L1` doesn't make sense combined with `-0` or `-I '{}'`. You probably meant `xargs -r0 -n1 rename '...'` or `xargs -r0 -I {} rename '...' {}`

Comment: Well, the `-L1` was just as I was worried regarding `rename`'s processing order.  I'll remove it, as there seems no trouble. Always a pleasure being corrected by you.

Comment: `-I {} cmd {}` calls cmd with one line of input (stripped of trailing blanks, and quoting still processed) as the one argument, or one record if `-0`/`-d` are specified. but with `-L 1 cmd`, that's `cmd` called with the words found in one line of input as arguments, and that reverts to `-n 1` when `-0`/`-d` is specified. In any case, `-L` is ignored when when `-I` is specified.

Comment: I see. Now I understand the poor performance. Should have stuck to the good old RTFM-guideline.... Without this it is indeed quite fast.